# How to make an input part of a random variable?

Tags: python

So I am coding a simple guessing game in python. I want to make it that you can choose up to what number you want the computer to guess. Starting from one. How do I make it so that the user input of an integer is the last number the computer will guess to? This is the code:

```
import random

while True:
    print("Welcome to odds on. Up to what number would you like to go to?")
    num = int(input())
    
    
    
    print("Welcome to odds on. Make your choice:")
    choice = int(input())

    cc = [1, num]

    print()

    computerchoice = random.choice(cc)
```

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you had something like this in mind. A guessing game that takes two inputs. Maximum integer and the users number choice and outputs if the user is correct or not. Game doesn't end because of the while-loop.

**Working Code:**

```
import random


while True:

    try:

        print("Welcome to GUESS THE NUMBER. Up to what number would you like to go to?")
        maxNum = int(input())

        if maxNum <= 1:
            print('Number has to be greater than 0')
            break            

        print("Guess the number:")
        choice = int(input())

        if choice <= 1:
            print('Your Choice has to be greater than 0')
            break

        correctNumber = random.randint(0,maxNum)

        if choice == correctNumber:
            print('CORRECT')
            break

        else:
            print('WRONG')

    except:
        ValueError
        print('Enter a number, not something else you idiot')
```

And here the same code but the user only has **3 retries**: (The indentations can be wrong if you copy paste my code)

```
import random

retry = 3

while retry != 0:

    try:

        print("Welcome to GUESS THE NUMBER. Up to what number would you like to go to?")
        maxNum = int(input())

        if maxNum <= 1:
            print('Number has to be greater than 0')
            break            

        print("Guess the number:")
        choice = int(input())

        if choice <= 1:
            print('Your Choice has to be greater than 0')
            break

        correctNumber = random.randint(0,maxNum)

        if choice == correctNumber:
            print('CORRECT')
            break


        else:
            print('WRONG')
            retry -= 1
    
    except:
            ValueError
            print('Enter a number, not something else you idiot')
    
    
if retry == 0:
    print('You LOOSER')
```

Answer (score 0):

*importing python builtin module*

> import random

*let's say*

> num = 10

> random.randint(1,num)

**the retuerned integer will be between 1, 10**

Comment: You should explain also what is your answer along with code or any equivalent example.